# How Prometheus subquery notation works?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am getting confused about how the [subquery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery) notation in prometheus (like `[5m:1m]`) is aggregating data. I know when I mention range selector as this `[5m]`, it aggregates every data point in each 5 minute window. But when I plot graphs for `[5m:1m]`, it shows entire different set of data and I do not know how it got there. The queries I am using are

```
sum_over_time(metric_name{labelName="label"}[5m])
sum_over_time(metric_name{labelName="label"}[5m:1m])
```

How these 2 are different and how do they calculate data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### General use for subqueries

Subqueries are an inline substitution for [recording rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/). They behave very similarly, but without actually producing stored metric.

So expression like `sum_over_time( (<some_query>) [5m:1m])` is equivalent to `sum_over_time(instance:some_query_result:resolution[5m])` with `evaluation_time` set to `1m` and recording rule

```yaml
- record: instance:some_query_result:resolution
  expr:   <some_query>
```

in place, where `<some_query>` is any query returning instant vector results.

Subqueries in promql are often used as a substitution for range selectors over something other than vector selector. For example, you can use `max_over_time(my_metric[2m])`, but you cannot use `max_over_time( (my_metric + my_other_metric) [2m])`: you need to use something like `max_over_time( (my_metric + my_other_metric) [2m:1s])` instead.

Of course, subquery can also be used with simple vector selectors. In that case it behaves as a range selector, but with additional `resolution`.

##### Resolution

Queries with resolution are executed in the following manner:
timeframe is divided into blocks of `resolution` length, and expression inside of subquery is evaluated at the end if each block. Then results of each evaluation are gathered according to range provided.

So in your example `sum_over_time(metric_name{labelName="label"}[5m:1m])`: value of `metric_name{labelName="label"}` will be taken on each minute, and then put into range of 5 minutes length. This will result in 5 samples, one for each minute, being put into range vector, and later being summed up by `sum_over_time`.

A couple important notices:

1. Evaluation is carried out on the "round" position relation to resolution. So if your resolution is `1m` evaluation will take place at every :00 second, if `1d` - every day at midnight (UTC), and if `17m` - every 17 minutes, with alignment point being 0 by epoch time<sup>1</sup>.
2. There is no limitation on relation of range and resolution. You are allowed to use query like `sum_over_time(up[1h:1d])`, and it will produce [interesting, but meaningful results](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=sum_over_time(up%5B1h%3A1d%5D)&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=2d).
3. Some functions like `rate`, `delta` and more are expecting at least two samples being present in provided range vector. Thus queries like `rate(metric[1m:1m])` will not yield any results, and something like `rate(metric[1m:57s])` will result in noncontinuous graph. [Demo](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=rate(node_cpu_seconds_total%5B1m%3A1m%5D)&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=5m&g0.step_input=1&g1.expr=rate(node_cpu_seconds_total%5B1m%3A57s%5D)&g1.tab=0&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=5m&g1.step_input=1&g2.expr=rate(node_cpu_seconds_total%5B1m%5D)&g2.tab=0&g2.stacked=0&g2.range_input=5m&g2.step_input=1).

---

<sup>1</sup> : not sure if it's officially guaranteed, as I haven't seen such in documentation, but this is how Prometheus is factually carrying out resolution (and evaluation of recording rules) and I don't see any reason for this to change in future.